# Азиатские письмена

Tags: pascal

не знаю, обязательно ли надо программу сюда вставлять, но у меня в итоговом txt файле вот ето:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить проблему? Должны быть числа для гнуплоте. При этом гнуплот читает файл, но ситуацию надо исправить...

Comment: Это про этот гнуплот вы писали? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot Вообще, скорее всего, программа данные записывает как бинарные, поэтому для человека они не понятны (это вам не json/xml/...), попробуйте в текстовом редакторе открыть фильм или картинку, тоже увидите кракозябры

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? Метка паскаля, значит вы хотите считать этот файл в свою программу, чтобы, самому отрисовать данные? Тогда нужно или найти описание формата гнуплот и сделать парсер, или найти библиотеку для вашего языка, что сможет с этим работать